# Trying to update rows of new column with different values depending on the vlue in another column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add a new column called vat_rate to a table called extra and then update the new column with values depending on what is in another column.

I have a CASE set up to change the values depending on the description column. But when I try to run the statement it says it matches all the rows, but does not change any and they stay null in the vat_rate column.

Here's a snip of how the extra table looks:

```
+----------+------------+--------------------+--------+----------+
| extra_id | booking_id | description        | amount | vat_rate |
+----------+------------+--------------------+--------+----------+
|   500101 |       5001 | Breakfast x 7      |  63.00 |     NULL |
|   500201 |       5002 | Breakfast x 2      |  18.00 |     NULL |
|   500301 |       5003 | Breakfast x 4      |  36.00 |     NULL |
|   500302 |       5003 | Phone Calls £4.69  |   4.69 |     NULL |
|   500402 |       5004 | Phone Calls £3.52  |   3.52 |     NULL |
```

and here are the statements I am using:

```
ALTER TABLE extra
ADD vat_rate double;

UPDATE extra SET vat_rate = (CASE
WHEN description = 'Phone%'
    THEN 20
WHEN description = 'Breakfast%'
    THEN 0
END);
```

What is wrong with the UPDATE statement I am using?

Comment: `=` and `%`... Use `LIKE` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like instead =

```
UPDATE extra SET vat_rate = (CASE
WHEN description like '%Phone%'
    THEN 20
WHEN description like '%Breakfast%'
    THEN 0
END);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%` wildcard does not have the intended effect when using `=` as the comparison operator - when you use `=` it's looking for an exact match to your stated string.

Instead you need to use the `LIKE` operator to allow `%` to match any number of characters after the static string:

```
UPDATE extra SET vat_rate = (CASE
WHEN description LIKE 'Phone%'
    THEN 20
WHEN description LIKE 'Breakfast%'
    THEN 0
END);
```

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like